# Get unexpected argc when use redirection

Tags: c, io-redirection

Here is the code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    fprintf(stderr,"arg count:%d\n",argc);
    return 0;
}
```

When type the following cmd:

```
./a.out x 3 >1.txt  //case1
```

I got argc 3. (in this case, a.out x and 3)

But when type the following cmd:

```
./a.out x 3>1.txt //case2
```

I got argc 2. It seems 3>1 was ignored.

I expected the argc is 3 like case1.

(Clarification: There is a space between 3 and > in case1)

Why I got 2nd case? And how to solve it?

Comment: I always find it necessary to separate the last program argument from any indirection mark. That is the solution.

Comment: BTW there is no pipe involved here. Redirections are _either_ to files or pipes, and yours are entirely files and not at all pipes. FYI, although people often write file redirections last on a command line, that is not required; `./a.out x >1.txt 3` and even `>1.txt ./a.out x 3` would work the same.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Didn't know it before. Thanks a lot. I have fixed the tile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you have to remember that all redirection is handled by the shell itself, it's not passed on to the program.

The command

```
./a.out x 3 >1.txt
```

have three arguments to `a.out`: The command itself, `x` and `3`.

With

```
./a.out x 3>1.txt
```

then `3>1` is all part of the redirection handled by the shell. It will redirect descriptor `3` to the file `1.txt`.

Comment: Wow. Got it. Thanks. I didn't realize 3 is interpreted as descriptor. I used it as a number.